# Drop Down Control Selected Index change event

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropdownbox

In my webfrom in asp.net I have a grid view a button, a text box and a Dropdownlist.
I have a method like this to call and select the data in to my grid view.

```
public void fillGridByAuthor(string searchKey)
{
    GVDetails.DataSource = new ViewAllBKByAuthorOP().searchAuthorByAUNM(searchKey);
    GVDetails.DataBind();
}
```

This is my business layer method.

```
 public DataTable searchAuthorByAUNM(string searchKey)
{
    string query2 = "EXEC SelectBooksDTByAuthor'" + searchKey + "'";
    return new DataAccessLayer().executeTable(query2);
}
```

I'm calling fillGridByAuthor method in form in the drop downlist selected index change event like this.

```
 protected void DDAuthor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    fillGridByAuthor(DDAuthor.Text);

 }
```

and in the button click event like this

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     fillGridByAuthor(txtAuName.Text);

 }
```

It is working fine when the button is clicked. Though I select the same Item in the drop down list, it doesn't give me the same output.
What's incorrect here?

Comment: Have u debugged the code and checked what value it is actually passing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set AutoPostBack property of your dropdownlist to true and it will work like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The `Text` property gets and sets the same value that the `SelectedValue`
>   property does. The `SelectedValue` property is commonly used to
>   determine the value of the selected item in the `ListControl` control.
>   If no item is selected, an empty string ("") is returned.

So the `Text` property returns the `Value` not the `Text` property of the currently selected item. Use `SelectedItem.Text` instead.

```
fillGridByAuthor(DDAuthor.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but setting the autopost back property of Drop downlist it worked.

Comment: @Sahil: then you haven't set the [`DataTextField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield(v=vs.110).aspx) and `DataValueField` accordingly, have you? However, you should start using the debugger since it's a powerful tool to find bugs.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, I just read about what you have mentioned. Thanks for the help again.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding autopostback = true to your dropdownlist. It will probably help

And, you should do this:

```
fillGridByAuthor(DDAuthor.SelectedValue);
```

**EDIT**

what Tim Schmelter is probably better because you want the text so:

```
fillGridByAuthor(DDAuthor.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but setting the autopost back property of Drop downlist it worked.